# Choicelessly assigning ordinals to fast growing functions

Tags: set-theory

Consider functions from the natural numbers to themselves. One can define a partial ordering on them by saying that, for $f, g: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, $f>g$ if there exists an integer $N$ such that for all $n > N, f(n) > g(n)$. Is there an choiceless order-preserving surjection from the set of functions from the natural numbers to themselves to the first uncountable ordinal? The map only needs to preserve $\geq$, not $>$.

Using the axiom of choice, one can construct an fast-growing hierarchy extending all the way to $\omega_1$ and this gives a valid surjection by assigning $\sup(\{\alpha| f_\alpha < f\})$ to each function $f$. There is apparently no injection from $\omega_1$ to the continuum constructable without the axiom of choice, so this means that no such hierarchy can be made choicelessly. There is a surjection from the continuum to $\omega_1$, though, so I was wondering if this weaker notion of a fast growing hierarchy can still exist.

Edit (Patching some loopholes): I was originally considering the existence of a map from $\omega_1$ to subsets of functions such that each subset is non-empty and each element of $f(\alpha)$ is greater than each element of $f(\beta)$ for $\alpha > \beta$, but I did the reduction wrong. One needs to loosen to a surjection out of a subset of the functions per Noah's comment and to demand that if $\phi$ is the surjection and $\phi(f) > \phi(g)$, then $f > g$.

Comment: The functions $f_{r}(n)=\text{integer part of}~rn$ are ordered in your sense and are in bijection with real numbers $r$. Perhaps this is relevant.

Comment: The first sentence of your second paragraph is wrong: it's consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that any size-$\aleph_1$ set of functions from naturals to naturals is dominated by a single function from naturals to naturals (in the language of cardinal characteristics of the continuum, this is what we get if $\mathfrak{b}>\aleph_1$), and such a function wouldn't be assigned an ordinal in what you describe. You seem to be *also* implicitly  assuming the continuum hypothesis.

Comment: You are right. I forgot to check the top too closely, and I don't know enough set theory to prove that anything is undecidable on my own.... 
Where did I use the continuum hypothesis?